# Polylang translating urls slugs not work correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, github, plugins, polylang

I'm using the Polylang wordpress plugin to transform my website into multiple languages.

In the free version it is not allowed to translate the category_base or Tags slug in permalinks.

So I tried to find a solution and I got involved in the plugin https://github.com/KLicheR/wp-polylang-translate-rewrite-slugs

that should do this, I installed the plugin and entered the following snippet in function.php:

```
add_filter( 'pll_translated_taxonomy_rewrite_slugs', function( $taxonomy_translated_slugs ) 
{
    $taxonomy_translated_slugs = array(

        // tax_name
        'category' => array(
            'it' => 'categoria',
            'en' => 'category',
        )

    );

    return $taxonomy_translated_slugs;
});
```

*the snippet I used was found in the plugin README: https://github.com/KLicheR/wp-polylang-translate-rewrite-slugs/blob/master/polylang-translate-rewrite-slugs.php*

I updated the Permalinks and it seems that now when I change the language the slug in the url changes.

I noticed though that in the HTML code the HREFLANG tags have a problem, not showing the correct URL.

the correct URLs are:

**IT: Mydomain.com/categoria/xxxxxxx**

**EN: Mydomain.com/en/category/yyyyyy**

going to see the HREFLANG tags in the html code I find myself instead:

```
<link rel = "alternate" href = "Mydomain.com/xxxxxxx" hreflang = "it" />
<link rel = "alternate" href = "Mydomain.com/en/yyyyyy" hreflang = "en" />
```

So the slugs "category" and "category" are eliminated.

The links in the language switcher widget also have the same problem.

Why not also update these elements?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? If yes, Can you post your solution here?